# jquery checkbox count in a foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

after looking almost everywhere I can't find a solution to my problem. Almost there but not working.
I have a foreach from my database who shows a list of materials in a table. Each material has a unique ID.
The goal is to have a table with each type of material and the quantity next to it. When I click on the row of a material , it expands all the other rows of this material and a checkbox next to it.
When I click on a checkbox, a counter increments.
I get it working but when I click on another material checkbox, it increments the first one and not the correct row. Hereby the code
Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("tr.clickable").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".clickable").toggle();
  });
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');        
    $checkboxes.change(function(){
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        var countDB = $('#countvalue').val();
        $('#sum').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
        if(countCheckedCheckboxes == countDB) {
        $('.clickable').css('background', '#7ed98e');}
    });
});
```

php

```
<?php
...
foreach($result3 as $row3) {
...
?>
        <tr class="clickable">
            <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" id="countvalue" value="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td id="sum">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="extra" style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3">
                <?php
                      ....
            foreach($result2 as $row2) { ?>
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                                <td style="width: 50px; padding-left: 10px">#<?php echo $row2["Missions_objects_idobject"]; ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 200px;padding-left: 10px"><?php echo $row2["Missions_objects_name"]; ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 20px;padding-left: 20px"><input type="checkbox" class="box"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                  <?php } ?>
       </td>
       </tr>
                   
 <?php } ?>
```

I would greatly appreciate some help. thanks

Comment: IDs need to be unique, you are violating that basic rule with the HTML content you are outputting multiple times in the loop there.

Comment: Further to the previous comment, you're asking for help with the client-side/front-end of your site which means the php is largely irrelevant. Can you post (an example of) the resulting HTML as seen by the browser (view source, copy and paste the `<table>`, or right click on the table contents, find the `<table>` DOM node in the inspector, right-click that node and "copy outerHTML"), obviously reduce that to a representative sample as the whole `<table>` is probably unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using id attribute when creating elements in loop because that will cause multiple elements with same DOM id, use class instead :

```
<?php
...
foreach($result3 as $row3) {
...
?>
        <tr class="clickable">
            <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" class="countvalue" value="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="extra" style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3">
                <?php
                      ....
            foreach($result2 as $row2) { ?>
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                                <td style="width: 50px; padding-left: 10px">#<?php echo $row2["Missions_objects_idobject"]; ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 200px;padding-left: 10px"><?php echo $row2["Missions_objects_name"]; ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 20px;padding-left: 20px"><input type="checkbox" class="box"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                  <?php } ?>
       </td>
       </tr>
                   
 <?php } ?>
```

and in js call the elements by class and select them by their parent :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.clickable").click(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil(".clickable").toggle();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');        
    $checkboxes.change(function(){
        $checkboxes_ = $(this).parents('.extra').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes_.filter(':checked').length;
        var countDB = $checkboxes_.parents('.extra').prev().find('.countvalue').val();
        $checkboxes_.parents('.extra').prev().find('.sum').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
        if(countCheckedCheckboxes == countDB) {
        $checkboxes_.parents('.extra').prev().css('background', '#7ed98e');}
    });
});
```